# Preprocessor macro calling inline function

Tags: c++

In my code I used preprocessor macro

```
#define BAR(x) x+2
```

but then I realized that I need an inline function in it's place and ended up with the following code

```
#define BAR(x) in_bar(x)

inline double in_bar(double x) {
  return x + 2;
}

void main() {
  std::cout << BAR(2) << std::endl;
}
```

Is it valid? It seems to work, but won't it cause any potential problems?

Comment: Why keeping the MACRO ?

Comment: @Jarod42 because otherwise I'd need to edit multiple files in multiple places and it is simply not worth wasting time on it...

Comment: How about `inline double BAR(double d) { return x + 2;}` ?

Comment: "edit multiple files in multiple places" - wait, you're using a macro like that in a header?  Jarod's suggestion of losing the macro should be seriously considered because a macro in a header can have all sorts of bad effects, especially when named something that is relatively common

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, that's obvious and that's what I'm considering, but still I'm interested in what would happen in the scenario above.

Comment: While you probably should be avoiding macros anyway, but was the "need" for the inline function because the original macro was "getting the answer wrong" and should have been `#define BAR(x) (x+2)`? (I.e. including parentheses around the expression so `BAR(4)*3` gives `18` instead of `10` as your original version would have done).

Comment: @Tim just edit the files. It'll take less than a minute given a decent editor or a script. The alternative is incidental complexity and confusion for whoever tries to pass &BAR to a function.

Answer (score 3):

It is valid but unnecessary. Instead call the inline function directly from `main`. Also, `main` should return `int`

```
inline double in_bar(double x) {
    return x + 2;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << in_bar(2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct, if you only commented on why the approach in the question is valid I'd be happy to accept your answer. Finally I ended up with using inline functions and editing the code as suggested by you and in the comments.

Comment: @Tim people have already suggested that the approach is valid because there is no logical/syntax error and compiles to the same assembly code. The macro `BAR` is redundant.

Comment: I *know* it is redundant, my question is simply if compiler would correctly deal with inline functions in the described scenario (since macro and inline functions ask compiler to do the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

Your original macro was broken, and using a function will correct that.

E.g. if someone wrote `bar(1<<2)*4` it would generate 1<<2+2*4, which is not what you expect.

If some of your code relied on that broken behavior the result will differ (but in most cases the function-variant will be better).
As others have suggested - just make BAR the inline function, without any macro.

BTW: The proper macro would be

```
#define BAR(x) ((x)+2)
```

Comment: Alternatively the original macro was correct, and using a function will cause an unwanted change in behaviour...

Comment: To me that is client code relying on broken code - and I added that in the answer, the effect is the same, i.e. the client becomes broken after the change. But without any documentation describing that behavior for the macro I say that the macro is broken.